# Does the magnetic force depend on the reference frame?

Tags: electromagnetism, reference-frames, relativity, observers

**Force due to a moving charge = qvB**

Immagine a charge moving with some velocity on earth and I calculate the force due to its magnetic field with Earth as reference frame for me.
An astronaut in space also calculates the force but space as reference frame.

*For ease lets imagine that everything is happening in XY-plane then the force would be perpendicular to both of us, so our motion in XY plane would hove no effect on the force.*

**The force calculated by me and the astronaut would be different...right? If so, then how is this possible that the force produced is different when it should be same?**

Comment: Please consider rephrasing your question (especially the second paragraph)  to make it as clear as possible. When you are asking a question involving relativity you don't want even a shred of uncertainty over what you are exactly asking.

Answer (score 4):

> Immagine a charge moving with some velocity on earth and I calculate the force due to its magnetic field with Earth as reference frame for me.

A charge that exists in the universe generates both an electric and a magnetic field, in general. An observer in the reference frame $S$ (whether at rest or integral with the charge) measures $\mathbf{E}, \mathbf{B}$ and a total force $\mathbf{F} = q(\mathbf{E} + \mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{B})$. An observer in $S'$ (whether at rest or integral with the charge) measures $\mathbf{E}', \mathbf{B}'$ and a total force $\mathbf{F}' = q(\mathbf{E}' + \mathbf{v}'\times\mathbf{B}')$.

The electric and magnetic field transform into each other as component of the electromagnetic tensor $F^{\mu\nu}$ under Lorentz transformations. Applying the just mentioned to the force expressions one obtains that the force transforms as the spatial components of a four-vector under change of reference frame.

Answer (score 1):

The [magnetic field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_field) and [velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity) [vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-vector) are not [Lorentz invariants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_covariance), so yes, the resulting force is [frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_frame_of_reference)-dependent.